# When i am trying to provide the Password in a Shell Script to Connect ot DB2 it is failing and showing Error

Tags: shell, db2

When i am trying to provide the Password in a Shell Script to Connect ot DB2 it is failing and showing Error

Shell Script -----

```
#!/bin/bash
getResults()
{
db2 "connect to xyz user sam using P333vLMP$dFa4M0"
echo "Connected"
}
getResults
```

---

```
$ sh connectdb2.sh
```

.  During SQL processing it returned:

> SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "24" ("USERNAME
>   AND/OR  PASSWORD INVALID").  SQLSTATE=08001 DB21034E  The command was
>   processed as an SQL statement because it was not a valid Command Line
>   Processor command

But when i dont provide the Password in the Shell Script it prompts for the Password and it is getting Connected.

My Question is that i dont want the password to be prompted rather Can anyone please help me to connect to DB2 by implicitly hard coding the passowrd within the shell script.

Thanks,
Samrat

Comment: You need to escape the $ to prevent the shell from interpolating. Example P333vLMP\$dFa4M0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hardcode a password in a shell script, it is an obvious security risk. Consider having the password in a separate file with special permissions that gets dotted in by your script.

However, if you do hardcode the password anywhere, then if the password contains characters that are meaningful to the shell (in your case bash), then you must escape those characters to ensure the shell ignores them.

For your password example instead of P333vLMP$dFa4M0  it should be P333vLMP\$dFa4M0
because the $ has special meaning to the shell.

Answer (score 0):

You may surround your password with single quotes to avoid possible misinterpretation of the special characters by unix shell. This may be useful if you don't know if the password contains some special character in advance.

```
printf "Password: "; stty -echo; read pwd; stty echo; db2 "connect to xyz user sam using '${pwd}'"
```